# How do I find out what SDKs an app is using?

Tags: ios, sdk

Was asked by one of our clients how I can find out what SDKs their app uses. It's an iOS app -- Do they need to grant me some kind of permission in Apple Dev?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xcodebuild -showsdks` will show you what sdks you have installed but I don't think that's what you're looking for.

The best way to do what you want to do would be:

1. Open the project for this app in xcode
2. Look for the part where it states the minimum required iOS
3. That is your sdk version